# Accessing data members of an inherited class

Tags: c#, inheritance

So I have 4 classes: Employee (base class), PartTime : Employee, FullTime : Employee, Manager : Employee. I'm trying to access unique but can't figure out exactly how. I tried casting but that didn't work. Here's what I have so far.

```
            Employee emp1 = new Manager();
            emp1.FirstName = txtFirst.Text;
            emp1.LastName = txtLast.Text;
            emp1.Ssn = Convert.ToInt32(txtSSN.Text);
            emp1.HireDate = Convert.ToInt32(txtHire.Text);
            emp1.TaxRate = Convert.ToDecimal(txtTax.Text);
            emp1.Email = txtEmail.Text;
            emp1.PhoneNum = Convert.ToInt32(txtPhone);

            if (emp1 is PartTime)
            {
                emp1.HourlyRate = txtRate.Text;
                emp1.HoursWorked = txtHrs.Text;
            } 
            if (emp1 is FullTime)
            {
                emp1.Salary = Convert.ToDecimal(txtSalary.Text);
                emp1.VacationDays = Convert.ToDouble(txtVacation.Text);
                emp1.SickDays = Convert.ToDouble(txtSick.Text);
                emp1.IsTaxExempt = comboTax.SelectedIndex == 0 ? true : false;
                emp1.HasInsurance = comboInsurance.SelectedIndex == 0 ? true : false;
            }
            if (emp1 is Manager)
            {
                (Manager)emp1.BonusEarned = Convert.ToDecimal(txtBonus.Text);
                (Manager)emp1.Department = comboDepartment.SelectedText;
                (Manager)emp1.OfficeLocation = txtOffice.Text;
            }
```

In this example, Manager has the properties BonusEarned, Department, and OfficeLocation but Employee, FullTime, and PartTime don't.

Comment: You just did `var emp1 = new Employee();`. How could `emp1` possibly be a `PartTime` or `FullTime` or whatever else a few lines later?

Comment: you're trying to do what?

Comment: I just threw that in there to emphasize that I had an employee object. It's actually got a lot more stuff behind it but I just can't figure out this snippet. I'll fix the post to make it more clear.

Comment: How did casting "not work?"

Comment: @zimdanen I was hoping to be able to access data members (BonusEarned, Department, and OfficeLocation) that are unique to Manager, however, I got the error 'EmployeeManagement.Employee' does not contain a definition for BonusEarned and no extension method 'BonusEarned'. So it's still staying as an Employee object instead of recognizing it as a Manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (pay attention to the parenthesis):

```
((Manager)emp1).BonusEarned = Convert.ToDecimal(txtBonus.Text);
((Manager)emp1).Department = comboDepartment.SelectedText;
((Manager)emp1).OfficeLocation = txtOffice.Text;
```

Comment: Ah of course. Works perfectly. Staring me straight in the face. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 1):

Ugh, I think that is just invalid syntax. You're doing cast in the LHS of an assignment statement... It doesn't work like that. Cast has to be on the RHS so the result can be assigned. Instead try something like this;

```
if (emp1 is Manager)
            {
                var man = (Manager)emp1
                man.BonusEarned = Convert.ToDecimal(txtBonus.Text);
                man.Department = comboDepartment.SelectedText;
                man.OfficeLocation = txtOffice.Text;
            }
```